# Set up 2 different custom error pages for 2 different parts of 1 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

Currently I'm having 1 custom error page for my whole ASP .NET site:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx" />
</system.web>
```

However, I would like to set up 2 different error pages, so that error on different part of the side will cause redirection to different error pages. For example:

- When users encounter an error in a page within `http://example.com/Part1/` they will be redirect to `ErrorPage1.aspx`.
- When users encounter an error in a page within `http://example.com/Part2/` they will be redirect to `ErrorPage2.aspx`

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Have you tried having web.config files in the individual folders?

Comment: @Adrian Wragg Works like a charm, if you post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Thanks - wasn't sure if it would work or not (and didn't have time to test), hence it originally only being a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET allows certain settings within `web.config` to be overridden in subdirectories; this includes the error handling. Simply create:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage1.aspx" />
</system.web>
```

as `Part1\web.config`, and

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage2.aspx" />
</system.web>
```

as `Part2\web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the page shown can only be based on the HTTP result code, like 500, 404, etc. as can be read [on this page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs). Quoted from there:

> "A better approach is to use a custom error page, which entails creating and designing the custom error page and specifying its URL in the  section's defaultRedirect attribute. You can even have multiple custom error pages for different HTTP error statuses."

You could use your own errorhandling in try/catch blocks and do the redirects manually there.